# convert PyFloatObject to float

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I have a `PyFloatObject` that I want to convert to a `C float`. However, `PyObjectFloat` only provides a conversion to double. Can I safely cast a double to a float, or is there a function to convert `PyObject` to `float` i.e. `PyObject_AsFloat`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric):

> Floating point numbers are usually implemented using `double` in C;

In other words, the Python `float` type is just a C `double`, so there is not magic Python function to convert a Python `float` to a C `float` other than what is normally available with C to convert `double` to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, as long as your 'double' will fit (with respect to magnitude) into a 'float'. however you may need to round it or truncate it to single precision.

using IEEE 754 floating point representations....

"float is defined as IEEE 754 single precision, double is defined as double precision, and long double is defined as IEEE 754 extended precision or some form of quad precision where available (e.g., Intel 80 bit double extended precision on x86 or x86-64 platforms), else double precision. Previously, all C90 floating operations were defined to occur in double-precision, with subsequent rounding to single precision, to store results, where necessary."

Data quoted regarding '754 is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99 (c99 c spec description on wikipedia) while it isn't python specific, IEEE 754 is general, and not c-specific)

What version of python are you using?  You may want to use (from https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/float.html)

double PyFloat_AsDouble(PyObject *pyfloat)
Return a C double representation of the contents of pyfloat. If pyfloat is not a Python floating point object but has a **float**() method, this method will first be called to convert pyfloat into a float. This method returns -1.0 upon failure, so one should call PyErr_Occurred() to check for errors.

Comment: my understanding is that the difference in size of both the exponent and mantissa would make manual coercion of a double to a float somewhat non-trivial and potentially dangerous

Comment: yes, the exponent is the 'fit' part.  Doubles and Floats are both approximations, there will be loss of precision in almost all conversion cases anyway.

Comment: loss of precision is inevitable, but bit level manipulation of doubles to approximate a float sounds like there would be inevitable edge cases in which serious errors occur  due to the primitive nature of the conversion method.

Answer (score 0):

sprintf into a buffer followed by atoi seems to do the trick